# Error using fminsearch and fminbnd

Tags: matlab, optimization, minimization

The function works well when called in the command window.

```
function z = values(x1)   
y = [9; 8; 6; 5; 6; 7; 8];    
x = [1; 2; 3; 4 ;5; 6; 7];    
a = find(abs(x-x1) < 0.001);    
z = y(a);    
plot(x,y);    
end
```

```
>>values(3)

ans=6
```

---

When I try to use `fminsearch` inbuilt MATLAB function as follows:

```
>> f = @values;                     
>> options = optimset('Display','iter','TolX',0.001);      
>> [xc, FunVal] = fminsearch(f, 2, options);
```

I  get the following error in the command window:

> ```
> Iteration   Func-count     min f(x)         Procedure
>
>      0            1                8
> ```
>
> Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.
>   Error in `fminsearch` (line 255)
>
> ```
> fv(1,j+1) = f;
> ```

---

When I try to use `fminbnd` inbuilt MATLAB function as follows:

```
>> f = @values;   
>> options = optimset('Display','iter','TolX',0.001);   
>> [xc, FunVal, EF, output] = fminbnd(f, 2, 6, options)
```

I  get the following error in the command window:

> `a = ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍
>          Empty matrix: 0-by-1 ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍`
>
> Error using `fminbnd` (line 220)
>   User supplied objective function must return a scalar value.

---

Why is this happening and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that your objective function returns nothing (empty) for some values. I just printed the input values (x1) to console. The first test is x1 = 2, which is the initial value. Then MATLAB test 2.1. However, a is emtpy for x1 = 2.1, since abs(x-2.1) is not < 0.001 for any value in x.

Therefore you get the errors.

Edit: I also really do not understang what the objectuve function is supposed to do.

Comment: Thank you for answering. The objective function is meant to minimize the function value.                                                                                                                               Actually, i have defined x and y value in discrete form. Thank you for pin pointing this ... I should defined the array where 'x' value takes 2,2.1,2.2 and so on and its corresponding function   'y'   value. Then 'a' would have not returned with an empty set.

Comment: If you just add values at 2.1, 2.2, etc. it will work for the next step, but not in general. What you need, and the reason I asked for the objective function, is that you have to write the function down in some parametric form, i.e. it returns a value for any x1.

Comment: Yes, I Will need to curve fitting polynomial method of highest order with lowest rmse.  By doing so, objective function is the polynomial equation. This objective function needs to be minimized to find local minima.